# How do I make a quick refference in angularjs between generated items with ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

First of all I am new to angularjs.
 I want to make a simple / quick  refference betweeen my anchors and paragraphs>inputs, depending on what I clicked in my angular web app.
 I generate 3 table rows with 1 table data with the ng-repeat. After this, when I click one of the anchors my toggleDetails(todo.id,todo.nume,todo.prenume) triggers and I update my next below input values (#inputId, #inputNume, #inputPrenume) with basic javascript. I feel like I m doing it hard way. Can I use less code like some angularjs directives ?(I`m using a Yeoman framework) So, this is my HTML:

```
<div class="container" controller="AboutCtrl">
   <h2>Lista persoane</h2>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <th>Nume si prenume</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="form-group " ng-repeat="todo in todos">
         <td>

           <a href ng-click="toggleDetails(todo.id,todo.nume,todo.prenume)">

               <input type="text" ng-model="todo.nume" class="form-control">

           </a>

         </td>
      </tr>
  </table>

  <div ng-hide="hideDetails">
    <p>Id:<input type="text" id="inputId"/></p><br>
    <p>Nume:<input type="text" id="inputNume"/></p><br>
    <p>Prenume:<input type="text" id="inputPrenume"/></p><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

About.js file

```
 .controller('AboutCtrl', function ($scope, AfisareDateService) {

    $scope.todos = [{

    id: 1,
    nume: 'name1',
    prenume: 'name2'},{

    id: 2,
    nume: 'name3',
    prenume: 'nam4'}, {

    id: 3,
    nume: 'name5',
    prenume: 'name6'

}];

$scope.hideDetails = true;

$scope.toggleDetails = function(id,nume,prenume) {
  $scope.hideDetails = !$scope.hideDetails;
  var x = document.getElementById('inputId');
  var y = document.getElementById('inputNume');
  var z = document.getElementById('inputPrenume');
  x.value = id;
  y.value = nume;
  z.value = prenume;
});
```

Comment: indeed you are doing it really hard way

Comment: You should never access the DOM from your JS except using custom built directives in angularjs.  Directives are used in the markup and modify the DOM elements they're applied to directly, accessing the DOM from your controllers or services will make them difficult to test without having something that builds the view.  Much of the time a built in directive will cover your needs or you can find third party directives with mixed quality and eventually learn to build your own to extend the behavior and language available in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few changes

```
$scope.toggleDetails = function(todo) {
  $scope.hideDetails = !$scope.hideDetails;
  $scope.selectedTodo = todo
});
```

and use ng-model

```
<p>Id:<input type="text" ng-model="selectedTodo.id"/></p><br>
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot about this

Answer (score 0):

```
In html change parameter of toggledetail
    <tr class="form-group " ng-repeat="todo in todos">
             <td>

               <a href ng-click="toggleDetails(todo)">

                   <input type="text" ng-model="todo.nume" class="form-control">

               </a>
 <div ng-show="Object.keys(selectedTodo).length>0">
        <p>Id:<input ng-model="selectedTodo.id type="text" id="inputId"/></p><br>
        <p>Nume:<input ng-model="selectedTodo.name"  type="text" id="inputNume"/></p><br>
        <p>Prenume:<input  ng-model="selectedTodo. prenume"  type="text" id="inputPrenume"/></p><br>
      </div>
    </div>
In controller
$scope.selectedTodo ={}   //take variable 
$scope.toggleDetails = function(todo) {
   $scope.selectedTodo = todo;
```